# Drop a Label in a TreeGrid

Tags: drag-and-drop, smartgwt, treegrid

I use SmartGWT 3.0, and I need to detect a drop of an external `Label` in a `TreeGrid`, I tried many ways to do that but none work.
In a `Canvas` I can do drop, but the `TreeGrid` doesn't detect the drop.
Is there any way to do that?

```
TreeGrid tileGrid = new TreeGrid();
tileGrid.setAlign(Alignment.CENTER);
tileGrid.setWidth(300);
tileGrid.setHeight(300);

tileGrid.setCanAcceptDrop(true);

tileGrid.addDropHandler(new DropHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onDrop(DropEvent event) {
         Window.alert("drop");
    }
});

Canvas cv = new Canvas();
cv.setBorder("1px solid #CCCCCC");
cv.setWidth(300);
cv.setHeight(300);
cv.setCanAcceptDrop(Boolean.TRUE);

cv.addDropHandler(new DropHandler() {

     @Override
     public void onDrop(DropEvent event) {
         Window.alert("drop event"+event.toString());
     }
});


Label lb = new Label("Drag me");
lb.setCanDrag(true);
lb.setCanDrop(true);
lb.setDragAppearance(DragAppearance.TARGET);

// added the components to a HLayout
panel.addMember(tileGrid);
panel.addMember(cv);
panel.addMember(lb);

panel.draw();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think in the case of the canvas, it can accept everything as data dropped. In the case of the TreeGrid it expect something related to a record....
I tested with overriding

```
TreeGrid tileGrid2 = new TreeGrid(){
            @Override
            public Boolean willAcceptDrop(){
                return new Boolean(true);
            }
        };
```

This in relation with [this thread](http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=3432)
And in this case The event is triggered but we get a javascript error so One solution will be to pickup the drag event from the label and create on the fly a TreeNode or something like that which could be accepted as dropped data on the grid side.
Hoping it could help....

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
TreeGrid.addFolderDropHandler();
```

Comment: Can you explain why this should be tried(although it's somewhat clear by the method name)?